# Disappearing 1px dotted border in Linux Google Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, border

While developing a site which I can't link to directly, I've found a following problem.

When a div's content makes it more than 4098px high, border disappears. Here's an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/ezimir/RzPSm/

This only appears on Linux (Ubuntu) (other browsers and OS' render this correctly). I'm currently using Google Chrome 12.0.742.112.

How to make that border stick on high elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same bug happens with (all Windows 7) these versions of Chrome:

- 12.0.742.112 (stable)
- 14.0.814.0 (dev)
- 14.0.814.0 (Canary)

It does not happen in Safari.

Therefore, you should file a bug report here: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list

Comment: Looks like it's already been filed: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=32702

Comment: That bug has been hanging around for an uncomfortably long time.. Thanks for the link.